# Toyota Corolla won't start without fiddling with the central locking first

Tags: starting, corolla

Something's happened recently, and I figured out to start the car, I needed to use the Central locking remote to lock and unlock the car while being inside to turn it on. The button for the remote is now damaged.

Is there another way of starting the car?

(Sorry, not sure of the make, model or year, this is for a friend, but I can get it if it's essential)

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with the immobiliser - and the lock/unlock cycle is resetting it...

Comment: @NickC is there a way to reset this permanently? He has to fiddle with this every time he gets in the car.

Answer (score 2):

### Disconnecting the Battery

One thing they could try is disconnecting the battery, starting the ignition to remove any current from within the system, reconnecting the battery and testing for the issue again to see if that has resolved the issue.

### Resetting the Immobiliser

Otherwise you'll want to tell your friend to look at the cars user manual in order to figure out how to do a proper immobiliser reset on their particular make and model of car. I am pretty sure that from what you've said that the problem lies with the cars immobiliser.